# Postgres running in Kubernetes drops connection

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have a Postgres instance deployed inside a Kubernetes cluster. I am able to use this fine for short queries.

However, I have some queries that take over a minute to complete.

For such queries, the connection to the client is dropped almost exactly after a minute every time. Paying attention to Postgres logs, it looks like Postgres doesn't even know about the connection dropping until after the long running query completes. So for every long-running query, I don't get a "disconnected" message until after the query duration message in the logs - which is long after the client already errored out saying the server dropped the connection.

I take this as a hint that the connection is being dropped by something between the client and the Postgres server - possibly the Kubernetes load balancer.

This is deployed using a "LoadBalancer" service in Kubernetes on AWS.

I'm looking for ideas on where to look for the root cause of this issue.

Comment: It's not Kubernetes, more probably Docker; it has a timeout for all sockets. You should look at the documentation for your version of Docker, and configure your application to release its connection pool before the timeout.

Comment: If it is due to load balancer, yes. The LB default timeout is 60 seconds. You need to configure the idle timeouts. Hope this link may helps, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html

Comment: Have you used features like PostgreSQL's slow-query log and the SQL `EXPLAIN` statement?  I'd try to make these queries run faster over trying to adjust timeouts: there can be several layers of proxies and gateways (especially if you're calling from outside the cluster) and each of them can impose a similar timeout.